# Second-screen app in violation with Google Play Developer Policies

Tags: google-play, policy-violation

We have received a notice from Google Play that our app will be removed if we do not provide them with login credentials in our app. The problem is that our app is a second-screen game, where the primary screen is a desktop game which provides a four digit code for people to enter in our app and log on to the game. Our app has been in the Play Store for years and is quite popular.

Google Play has given us until Oct 4th to provide them with a code, otherwise our app "may be removed from the Play Store". We have set up a desktop computer running games in loop 24-7 until they have reviewed our app, and we have provided them with a link to a twitch stream where the game runs in loop.

It's now been seven days and we have not heard anything from Google Play. It's very frustrating that there is no personal contact, we only receive auto-generated bot/AI mails about policy violation.

Does anyone know what further action we can take to make sure our app is not removed? We have "contacted support", although contacting support in Google Play means just writing your app name and email address in a form and selecting a radio button of what the problem seems to be (none of them apply exactly). No response for days.

This is the original warning mail from Google Play:

> Hi Developers at xxx, After a recent review, we’ve identified that we
> need additional information about your app xxx in accordance with our
> policies. Please resolve the issue described below by October 04, 2022
> to avoid further action against your app. Reasons of violation     Issue:
> Need login credentials for app review In order for us to review your
> app for compliance with Developer Program Policies, we will need you
> to provide valid login credentials for your app.  If users need
> credentials to access your app, please provide all appropriate
> credentials via Play Console.  If you previously supplied credentials,
> please ensure that they have not expired.  If your app normally uses
> 2-Step Verification (e.g. SMS verification), biometrics (e.g. a
> fingerprint or face scan) or a location-dependent password (e.g.
> geo-gate), please provide valid demo credentials that we can use
> instead.

Answer (score 1):

in Google Play Console in `app content` > `app access` > `Add new instructions`

in `password` field write down the 4-digit code.

in `Any other instructions` Write a detailed step-by-step guide on how to walk through game until the 4-digit code entered, and provide them with a valid digit code (that always works) and write that this is a "Demo Digit code".
Also, provide them with a video just to the point of entering the code and logging in (the shorter the video the better)

And you will have to wait, it takes a lot of time do not worry.

Comment: I did all of this already Friday, however the 4-digit code is dynamic and changes with every game (every 10 minutes). I will try to stay calm but it's very frustrating that there is noone to contact. Thanks anyway for confirming that I have done the right thing :)

Comment: @AndersEmil you should have a 4-digits code that works every time. if this is not possible you can give Google Play a deep link that activate a specific 4-digit code

Comment: It worked! Google have removed the policy violation notice, so looks like they accepted the solution. Thank you for sharing the details.